# How do I properly put embedded ruby code in to JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, sinatra

I am trying to embed the output of Ruby code in JavaScript:

```
var stuff= "<% Representative.get('http://0.0.0.0:4568/') %>";
```

The embedded part is working by itself showing a result like this:

```
{ "name":"John Johnson", "street":"Oslo West 555", "age":33, "phone":"555 1234567"}
```

The line above is the EXACT PAGE SOURCE; it runs locally though, so I can't show you the page.

When in a variable, I try to send it to my application with this:

```
document.getElementById("X_Axis").value=stuff.name;
```

through the input:

```
<input type="text" id="X_Axis" />
```

I get a `undefined` value every time.

I tried hardcoding the value in the JavaScript and it works fine like that, put when the embedded Ruby is put into the JavaScript variable, it always gives me the `undefined` value.

Comment: is X_Axis available to the DOM @ the time you call your function ?

Comment: Yes, I have tried hardcodeing it in the same place as where i transfer the erb to js and it works. My money is on the qoutation marks of the embeded part while transfering it to js, but i have to find out how to remove the qoutation marks with a regex. Although, it won't work without them while transfering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be putting quotes around your ERB code, otherwise it puts the results in a string instead of assigning it to `stuff` as a hash/JSON object. Remove them and it should work. (Also, `<%` should be `<%=`).

```
var stuff = <%= Representative.get('http://0.0.0.0:4568/') %>;
```

Comment: I have tried it like that (and now once again) and then my code stops working. Maybe somehow to transfer it to a json object from string?

Comment: Also, with the `<%=` it won't work. And I don't see why I should put it like that, i don't want it on the screen, just in the variable.

Comment: Yes, but the `<%=` doesn't mean "put it on screen", it means "write it into the HTML, which is what you want so that it places it next to the `var stuff = `. Can you update your question showing the exact page source that's generated with your current code?

Comment: the `{
"name":"John Johnson",
"street":"Oslo West 555",
"age":33,
"phone":"555 1234567"}
` is the exact page source. I have it locally though so I can't show you.

Comment: So if you right-click and do View Source on your page, you only see the JSON results, you don't see `var stuff = ` anywhere??

Comment: Yeah, the `var stuff =` is in the html tags `<script type = text/javascript></script>` of my application.

Comment: Maybe it is confusing but... i have my application on one server and writting it in Ruby w/ Sinatra and on another server that JSON result. So I am picking up the json file with the first app with the httparty protocol and trying to show it in the browser. Hope I kind of cleared that out

Comment: Sorry Dylan! I just got what you ment, you were right the first time, removing the qoutations and putting the `<%=` worked. THANKS A MILLION :)